# URL rewrite issue in template file with WordPress

Tags: regex, wordpress, url-rewriting

I've made a PHP template file called `page-house.php` (this is standard WordPress template). So the website link is: `www.example.com/house`.

I've used this page template at `/house` and I would like it to be a dynamic url, so I can use `/house/1212` to show as a clean URL where its rewritten from `/house?houseid=1212`.

This is what we're trying. We edited the `functions.php` file and added in:

```
function custom_rewrite_tag() {
  add_rewrite_tag('%house%', '([^&]+)');
}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_tag', 10, 0);

function custom_rewrite_rule() {
add_rewrite_rule('/house/([^/]*)/?','/house?houseid=$matches[1]','top');
}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_rule', 10, 0);
```

If I visit `www.example.com/house/1212`, I will get a `404 page: Not found error`. When I manually enter `www.example.com/house?houseid=1212`, the required template file will load. I've gone to settings and refreshed the permalink settings multiple times, but it still doesn't work.

I think its some regex issue what we cannot figure out. Is there anything else that we need to do?